# How do I make a path from selected anchors points in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, path, selections

I have Illustrator cs6. I would like to make a path from selected vertices (anchor points) in different objects created with the pen tool. Is this possible? All the path-from-selection methods I've seen on this site seem to be for Photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

If these anchor points are unconnected or have at least one open end, then you can simply use the Join command (`Object > Path > Join`).

If these anchor points already have 2 paths connected to them, **no** you won't be able to connect a third path to the anchor points. Illustrator anchors have an "in" and an "out" direction and that's all they can do. In other words you can never make a "T" joint with one anchor point. It's simply not possible in Illustrator.

Answer (score 1):

Scott hit the nail on the head by saying this isn't possible. You can work around this, however, by making clever use of the Smart Guides.

1. Ensure your Smart Guides are switched on (<kbd>View > Smart Guides</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and that snapping to all kinds of grid is turned off. Turn Snap to Point on (<kbd>View > Snap to Point</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd>.
2. Choose the objects you want to use anchors from and collect them in a single layer in the Layers palette (<kbd>F7</kbd> or <kbd>Window > Layers</kbd>).
3. Lock the layer. You can do so by clicking the empty square in the Layers palette, next to the eye icon. A lock icon should appear there.
4. Create a new layer to draw on.
5. Use the pen tool to draw your path. The Smart Guides should help you find the exact positions of the desired anchors, they will be mentioned as 'anchor' in green once you hover close enough.

Comment: without locking any layer, you can start drawing in any white space and continue drawing snapping to any anchor with smart guide on.